# how to give Versioning from bundleconfig bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Controllers").IncludeDirectory("~/App/Controllers", "*.js", true));

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

How to give versioning for .js which are loading from bundle Config, like as below

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Controllers").IncludeDirectory("~/App/Controllers", "*.js", true));
```

Comment: Its already there see https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Comment: As per the provided link ,if there are changes in bundle config. then  version is uniquely generated by asp .net  framework. but in my case I am not able to see any version for controller java script files. So please suggest more ways..